# Delete api request ReactJS and Express with Axios returning 404 Error message

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I am getting error as
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
at createError (createError.js:16)
at settle (settle.js:17)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)

Comment: Without a [mcve], this could be anything.

Comment: Please post the revenant code for this issue